# android tablet locked after too many unlocking pattern attempts

Tags: system-error

After too many unlocking pattern attempts, my android tablet have locked me out..

How do i fix this? Is there a manually direction on how to unlock my tablet?

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting the tablet by using reset button, usually this button is not very visible and would need a pointed object to press it, check manual to find location.

Comment: How can you suggest this without knowing what tablet it is?  A guess at best. I've never actually seen a tablet with one of these, usually a hard rest is done by holding down the power button for ~20 seconds.